# Maximum amount of iterations to get to an empty list from repeatedly taking the smallest complement of a list

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

I was trying to solve [Iterative Smallest Complement](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248972/iterative-smallest-complement) on the Code Golf website, and thought of an interesting question.

A basic run down of what the smallest complement of a list is:

> ... `B` is a complement of `A` if:
>
> - `B` has all of the integers between the minimum and maximum of `A` which are missing from `A`, and
> - `B` has none of the integers present in `A`

So basically, you make the list $[\min(A)\ldots\max(A)]\backslash A$, where $\backslash$ represents set difference.

Now given a list of non-repeating numbers $A$, repeatedly find the smallest complement until you obtain the empty set, and record how many iterations it took. Iterations include the initial list $A$ and the empty set: $\{\}$.

For example, given $A=[1,3,4,5,8]$, the iterations are as follows:

1. $[1,3,4,5,8]$
2. $[2,6,7]$
3. $[3,4,5]$
4. $[]$

So, $4$ iterations when $A=[1,3,4,5,8]$.

---

Now I was wondering: For any given list $L$ which includes no repeating numbers, what is the highest amount of iterations possible? I'm looking for some kind of expression in terms of $L$ (like its length, or maximum value, etc.).

I'm also wondering if there is some kind of algorithm which can generate a list with the most amount of iterations.

Comment: Unsure if I am misunderstanding the problem.  I could be mistaken.  Wouldn't the list look like $\{1,3,5,7,9,11,\cdots,19\}$, for example?  That is, it seems as if the more gaps, the more iterations.

Comment: @user2661923 I don't know (that's why I'm asking this question in the first place), why don't you post an answer explaining why that is?

Comment: Because my response is speculative.  Even if I have understood the problem correctly, I am unsure of my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, having every second element should maximize the iterations. *We should be able to prove the following (based on [computed examples](https://pastebin.com/Rub79BZV)):* Considering all subsets of $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, n\}$. The maximal number of iterations (including initial input set and last empty set) is $\left\lfloor\frac{n+4}{2}\right\rfloor$. When $n$ is even, only the subset containing all even numbers achieves the maximum. When $n$ is odd, additional $n+1$ examples achieve the maximum (substitute some odd numbers into the even subset).

Answer (score 1):

Line up the integers from $\min(A)$ to $\max(A)$ (inclusive) in order and color everyone $\in A$ red and everyone else blue.  E.g. $\color{red}{1} \color{blue}{2} \color{red}{3 4 5} \color{blue}{6 7} \color{red}{8}$.

Define a *block* as a maximal-sized sequence of consecutive same colored integers.  E.g. the above example has $5$ blocks.  The number of transitions would be $\frac{B+1}{2}$ where $B$ is the number of blocks, since each transition (except the last) removes the outermost two (same colored) blocks and then flip each remaining block's color, and the last transition removes the last block.  Since you count the original as an iteration also, the answer is $1 + \frac{B+1}{2}$.

It is therefore clear that for any given $\min(A), \max(A)$ the number of iterations is maximized if you maximize the number of blocks, i.e. include every other number in $A$ (subject to parity).